# @login_requred decorator for authentication using mongoengine in django

Tags: python-2.7, mongoengine, django-1.3

I am new to mongoengine I wanted to use @login_required decorator for checking whether user is logged in or not.
I used following code :
'''
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required(login_url='/loginpage')
def index(request):

```
return render_to_response('index.html')
```

'''

But above code is not working.Even though I submit correct username and passwrd it redirects to login page.
Anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve my goal or know of any articles/examples that could help me along?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are doing is right ... @login_required definitely works with mongoengine - i use it all over the place.

Take a look at the code here:

https://github.com/hmarr/django-mumblr/blob/master/mumblr/views/admin.py

Also, you need to use mongoengine sessions, if you are not already: